# Reading and writing binary file

Tags: c++, file, binary, buffer

I'm trying to write code to read a binary file into a buffer, then write the buffer to another file.  I have the following code, but the buffer only stores a couple of ASCII characters from the first line in the file and nothing else.

```
int length;
char * buffer;

ifstream is;
is.open ("C:\\Final.gif", ios::binary );
// get length of file:
is.seekg (0, ios::end);
length = is.tellg();
is.seekg (0, ios::beg);
// allocate memory:
buffer = new char [length];
// read data as a block:
is.read (buffer,length);
is.close();

FILE *pFile;
pFile = fopen ("C:\\myfile.gif", "w");
fwrite (buffer , 1 , sizeof(buffer) , pFile );
```

Comment: You should decide to use iostream or C file handling. Please do not use both.

Comment: There is a mistake in the above code regarding the buffer variable. It's type should be `unsigned char` and the allocation should be `buffer = new unsigned char[length + 1]` and then `buffer[length] = '\0'`. I know that the question was posted many years ago, but nobody has written about this.

Comment: @RalucaPandaru, given the input file is a GIF and explicitly read as `ios::binary`, adding a zero-terminator as you suggested makes no sense. Also difference between using a `char` or `unsigned char` does not make much difference here, as the code is not trying to interpret the file content.
What is wrong with the above code is the `sizeof(buffer)` is 4 or 8 (32/64-bit pointer). So it always writes 4/8 bytes into the output file.
Author should use `length` instead of `sizeof(buffer)`.

Answer (score 244, accepted):

If you want to do this the C++ way, do it like this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream input( "C:\\Final.gif", std::ios::binary );
    std::ofstream output( "C:\\myfile.gif", std::ios::binary );

    std::copy( 
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(input), 
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>( ),
        std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(output));
}
```

If you need that data in a buffer to modify it or something, do this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream input( "C:\\Final.gif", std::ios::binary );

    // copies all data into buffer
    std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(input), {});

}
```

Comment: What if I want copy only some segment of data to buffer. How I can do it? Let say 1024 bytes.

Comment: @Mikhail [Here](http://insanecoding.blogspot.it/2011/11/how-to-read-in-file-in-c.html) you can find some benchmarking.

Comment: AFAIK, binary files sometimes contain unreadable char, in the fact, they are not char at all. Is this code safe for reading non-text base file? My knowledge is short in this range :)

Comment: That's a really good question, I can't tell you that. I think it depends on the default locale used by your system, but I really have no experience with that either. For me, this has always worked reliably as a byte-by-byte copy operation.

Comment: so-called `char` is used in C/C++ to store bytes (and have been for the last 40 years). it's safe to do so, as long as you don't try to actually **USE** that data as characters (don't use strlen() on it, don't print it to console, etc). 

c++17 introduces `std::byte` for this purpose (which is still char actually `char` in disguise)

Comment: This doesn't work for me, it's not reading anything. Why is that?

Comment: @DavidTran Can't say without knowing more - this seems like you should create a minimal example that reproduces the issue, and then post a question.

Comment: it would be nice to add error handling to those lines of code!

Comment: How to handle: expected expression
    std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(input), {});

Comment: I love the two-line solution for reading into a buffer - the most succinct code I've seen to accomplish this!

Answer (score 17):

Here is a short example, the C++ way using `rdbuf`.  I got this from the web.  I can't find my original source on this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main () 
{
  std::ifstream f1 ("C:\\me.txt",std::fstream::binary);

  std::ofstream f2 ("C:\\me2.doc",std::fstream::trunc|std::fstream::binary);

  f2<<f1.rdbuf();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The best, non portable, method is to let the OS copy your file.  After all, that is part of what it does for a living; no need to *reinvent the wheel*.

Answer (score 15):

```
 sizeof(buffer) == sizeof(char*)
```

Use length instead.

Also, better to use `fopen` with "`wb`"....

Comment: Can't use `buffer.length()` for buffer may have NULL values inside it thereby defeating the purpose of strlen/length().

Comment: Better to use `sizeof(buffer)`.

Answer (score 10):

sizeof(buffer) is the size of a pointer on your last line NOT the actual size of the buffer.
You need to use "length" that you already established instead

Answer (score 6):

You should pass length into fwrite instead of sizeof(buffer).

Answer (score 5):

Here is implementation of standard C++ 14 using **vectors** and **tuples** to Read and Write Text, Binary and Hex files.

Snippet code :

```
try {
    if (file_type == BINARY_FILE) {

        /*Open the stream in binary mode.*/
        std::ifstream bin_file(file_name, std::ios::binary);

        if (bin_file.good()) {
            /*Read Binary data using streambuffer iterators.*/
            std::vector<uint8_t> v_buf((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(bin_file)), (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
            vec_buf = v_buf;
            bin_file.close();
        }

        else {
            throw std::exception();
        }

    }

    else if (file_type == ASCII_FILE) {

        /*Open the stream in default mode.*/
        std::ifstream ascii_file(file_name);
        string ascii_data;

        if (ascii_file.good()) {
            /*Read ASCII data using getline*/
            while (getline(ascii_file, ascii_data))
                str_buf += ascii_data + "\n";

            ascii_file.close();
        }
        else {
            throw std::exception();
        }
    }

    else if (file_type == HEX_FILE) {

        /*Open the stream in default mode.*/
        std::ifstream hex_file(file_name);

        if (hex_file.good()) {
            /*Read Hex data using streambuffer iterators.*/
            std::vector<char> h_buf((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(hex_file)), (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
            string hex_str_buf(h_buf.begin(), h_buf.end());
            hex_buf = hex_str_buf;

            hex_file.close();
        }
        else {
            throw std::exception();
        }
    }

}
```

Full Source code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/haseeb-heaven/ee3f5931f7951106bea550c119a68c57)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with simple commands in the following snippet.

Copies the whole file of any size. No size constraint!

Just use this. Tested And Working!!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  ifstream infile;
  infile.open("source.pdf",ios::binary|ios::in);

  ofstream outfile;
  outfile.open("temppdf.pdf",ios::binary|ios::out);

  int buffer[2];
  while(infile.read((char *)&buffer,sizeof(buffer)))
  {
      outfile.write((char *)&buffer,sizeof(buffer));
  }

  infile.close();
  outfile.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Having a smaller buffer size would be helpful in copying tiny files. Even "char buffer[2]"
would do the job.

Comment: And what if file size isn't multiple of buffer size? Moreover, why do you have to declare your buffer as `int[]` instead of `char[]`?

Comment: I already mentioned it works with `char[]` too and files of any size which means there's no condition that file size should be a multiple of buffer size.

Comment: The fact that you said it works does not mean it works. The fact that it does not work means it does not work.

Comment: The least you could do is to change 'int buffer[2]' to 'char buffer[1]' to make things work without changing the code to fix bugs.

Answer (score -2):

There is a much simpler way. This does not care if it is binary or text file.

Use noskipws.

```
char buf[SZ];
ifstream f("file");
int i;
for(i=0; f >> noskipws >> buffer[i]; i++);
ofstream f2("writeto");
for(int j=0; j < i; j++) f2 << noskipws << buffer[j];
```

Or you can just use string instead of the buffer.

```
string s; char c;
ifstream f("image.jpg");
while(f >> noskipws >> c) s += c;
ofstream f2("copy.jpg");
f2 << s;
```

normally stream skips white space characters like space or new line, tab and all other control characters.
But noskipws makes all the characters transferred.
So this will not only copy a text file but also a binary file.
And stream uses buffer internally, I assume the speed won't be slow.

Comment: You might want to elaborate on this to make it more understandable