# C++ reading and writing a file results in garbage

Tags: c++

I'm simply trying to read a small 1KB binary file into a buffer and then write the buffer back to the disk. It seems that for some files the outputfile is completely different from the Inputfile, what am I doing wrong?
Thank you very much.

```
std::ifstream myfile;
myfile.open (testinput.rar);            
myfile.seekg (0, myfile.end);
filesize = myfile.tellg();
myfile.seekg (0, myfile.beg);

char *mybuffer= new char[filesize];
myfile.read(mybuffer,filesize); 
myfile.close();             

ofstream myfile3;
myfile3.open ("testoutput.rar");
for(unsigned int i=0; i<filesize; i++)
    myfile3 << mybuffer[i]; 
myfile3.close();
```

Comment: It's been a while, but I think the file variable needs to be set to binary mode for binary data...

Comment: Should there be quotes round the parameter in `myfile.open (testinput.rar);`?  Can't imagine that would even build.

Comment: @user1158692 Yes, of course there should be quotes around the file name parameter. http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading and writing binary file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420317/reading-and-writing-binary-file)

Answer (score 1):

You have to open the file as binary.

```
myfile.open ("testinput.rar", std::ios::binary);
```

Answer (score 1):

`myfile3` should be opened in binary mode:

```
myfile3.open("testoutput.rar", ios::out | ios::binary);
```

Additionally, you may want to consider using `write()` to modify files:

```
myfile3.write(mybuffer[i], sizeOfBuffer);
```