# Writing/reading std::complex values in binary file

Tags: c++, binary

I pretend to store a `std::vector` of `std::complex<float>` in a binary file, and to later load that data into a std::vector again. I have checked similar questions in SO and came up with the following code:

```
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
typedef vector<complex<float>> complex_vector;


float get_random(){
    static std::default_random_engine e;
    static std::uniform_real_distribution<> dis(-10, 10);
    return dis(e);
}

int main(){
    // Random number generator
    srand(static_cast<unsigned> (time(0)));

    // Create a vector with 25 random complex<float> values
    std::shared_ptr<vector<complex<float>>> buffer = std::make_shared<vector<complex<float>>>();
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<25; i++){
        buffer->push_back(complex<float>(get_random(), get_random()));
    }

    // Write those values into a binary file
    std::string binFileName = "aux.bin";
    std::ofstream rawFile(binFileName, std::ios::binary);
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<buffer->size(); i++){
        rawFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&buffer->at(i)), sizeof(complex<float>));
    }
    rawFile.close();

    // Load the binary file into the buffer
    std::ifstream input(binFileName, std::ios::binary);
    complex_vector auxBuffer{std::istream_iterator<complex<float>>(input), std::istream_iterator<complex<float>>()};
    unsigned int samplesRead = auxBuffer.size();
    std::cout << samplesRead;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0
```

What am I missing?

EDIT:
After NathanOliver's answer, this is how my code looks like now:

```
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
typedef vector<complex<float>> complex_vector;


float get_random(){
    static std::default_random_engine e;
    static std::uniform_real_distribution<> dis(-10, 10);
    return dis(e);
}

int main(){
    // Random number generator
    srand(static_cast<unsigned> (time(0)));

    // Create a vector with 25 random complex<float> values
    std::shared_ptr<complex_vector> buffer = std::make_shared<complex_vector>();
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<25; i++){
        buffer->push_back(complex<float>(get_random(), get_random()));
    }

    // Write those values into a binary file
    std::string binFileName = "aux.bin";
    std::ofstream rawFile(binFileName, std::ios::binary);
    rawFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(buffer->size()), sizeof(buffer->size()));
    rawFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(buffer->data()), sizeof(std::complex<float>) * buffer->size());
    rawFile.close();

    // Load the binary file into the buffer
    std::ifstream input(binFileName, std::ios::binary);
    complex_vector::size_type nSamples;
    input.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(nSamples), sizeof(complex_vector::size_type));
    std::cout << nSamples;
    complex_vector *destination = new complex_vector(25);
    input.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(destination->data()), sizeof(std::complex<float>) * nSamples);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting a SIGSEGV in the first call to write function.

Also, I don't understand why I write , but I have to read .

Comment: You are probably missing the `std::ios::out` and `std::ios::in` flags.  Did you check if your file was actually created and contains data?

Comment: You can't mix binary writes with formatted reads.  If you `write` the data you need to `read` the data.  To make like easier you should `write` the size of the vector first that way you can `read` it in and allocate the storage so you can `read` in the data.

Comment: And dont mix `srand` with `std::default_random_engine` :)

Comment: @NathanOliver where's exactly the problem? I saw similar examples done just like this... I am both writing and reading in binary, so I don't understand what's wrong

Comment: Your not reading in binary.  `complex_vector auxBuffer{std::istream_iterator<complex<float>>(input), std::istream_iterator<complex<float>>()};` does not do a binary read even if the file is open in binary mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mix binary writes with formatted reads which is what you are doing right now.  Even though the file is opened in binary mode

```
complex_vector auxBuffer{std::istream_iterator<complex<float>>(input), std::istream_iterator<complex<float>>()};
```

calls the operator >>`of`complex>`and not`read`which is what you should use if you write the data with`write`.

You have two ways you can fix this.  You can do formatted writes instead of binary like

```
for (const auto& e : *buffer)
    rawFile << e << "\n"; // or space or any other white space delimiter
```

And then you would read it in exactly as you have it.

Your other option is to `write` the size of the vector and the contents of the vector and then `read` those both back in like

```
// write the size of the vector
rawFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&buffer->size()), sizeof(buffer->size()));
// write the whole contents of the vector in one go
rawFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(buffer->data()), sizeof(std::complex<float>) * buffer->size());

// and then to read it back in we get the size
complex_vector::size_type size;
input.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&size), sizeof(size));
// construct a vector of that size
complex_vector auxBuffer(size);
// and then read the data back into the vector
input.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(auxBuffer.data()), sizeof(std::complex<float>) * auxBuffer->size());
```

Personally I like the first option as it looks a lot cleaner but if this is performance sensitive then binary mode is typically faster.

Comment: I need it to be binary due to the size of the output files, which gets too heavy. Second option does not compile: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘std::basic_istream<char>::char_type* {aka char*}’ [-fpermissive] (on the first read call). Also, I don't understand why it doesn't work as I tried, just as specified here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5420568/808091

Comment: @RomanRdgz I had an error in the code.  The calls to write needed to use `reinterpret_cast<char*>` and not `reinterpret_cast<const char*>`.  The code has been updated.

Comment: Still does not seem to work: http://cpp.sh/7fhuz Plus, in my local code, I am getting a SIGSEGV at the first write

Comment: @RomanRdgz It is not going to work on C++ Shell as you cannot create files.  I did find another bug and `sizeof(std::complex<float>) * buffer->size()` should be `sizeof(std::complex<float>) * auxBuffer->size()`.  So `rawFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(buffer->size()), sizeof(buffer->size()));` gives you a sigsev?

Comment: That's right, I'm getting a SIGSEGV right there. Previously I'm declaring std::ofstream rawFile("aux.bin", std::ios::binary); and the file does get created. Next line is the write one with the sigsegv and don't know why

Comment: @RomanRdgz Your not writing it inside a for loop anymore are you?  I'm going to set this up on my machine latter today and see what happens.  I could have missed something.

Comment: No, not anymore. I'll edit the question with my current code

Comment: Missing '&' in rawFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&buffer->size()), sizeof(buffer->size())); was the problem. Now working!

Comment: @RomanRdgz Awesome.  Sorry about that,  Forgot I was dealing with a pointer.