# How can I read all hex values of ciphertext?

Tags: c++, encryption, hex, ifstream

There is a *ciphertext* without any extension which has 32 bytes size. Therefore, I can get its hex values with hex editor, and its hex values are;

a3 0b 35 8f 14 4e fe 5e 27 5a bd 8c 53 8b a0 cb ae da d3 fc 87 8b 51 0b d6 37 3e 91 86 9f f3 c9

I tried to read these values from ciphertext with my code which is,

```
ifstream stream;
unsigned char c;
char arr[2];
char cipherhex[65];
int i=0;
stream.open("ciphertext2");
while (!stream.eof()) {
    stream >> c;
    sprintf(arr, "%02x", c);
    cout << arr[0] << arr[1] << " ";
    cipherhex[i] = arr[0];
    cipherhex[i+1] = arr[1];
    i += 2;
}
```

However, when I run this code, although there is a condition for *0x* kind of hex values, it can read these hex values;

a3 35 8f 14 4e fe 5e 27 5a bd 8c 53 8b a0 cb ae da d3 fc 87 8b 51 d6 37 3e 91 86 9f f3 c9 c9

The code cannot read *0b*, *09*, *0c* , but for different ciphertexts it can read *03* or *0e* . I could not understand how it can read *03* and *0e* but cannot *09* or *0b*. Thanks in advance.

**Generally, there is no problem with reading hex values, but there is problem with reading specific values that I mentioned above.**

Comment: [read binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420317/reading-and-writing-binary-file)

Comment: Unfortunately, these answers are useless for me. I just get meaningless characters with them

Comment: `0b`, `09`, `0c`, are whitespace characters that are normally ignored by `operator>>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has several mistakes in it:

- not opening the file in binary mode.
- using `operator>>` to read *formatted* characters, which ignores whitespace characters.
- not allocating enough memory for `arr[]`, causing a buffer overflow in `sprintf()`.
- [using `!eof()` as your loop condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/).
- not null-terminating `cipherhex` after reading is done <sup>(optional)</sup>.

Try this instead:

```
ifstream stream;
char c, arr[3], cipherhex[65];
int cypherhexlen = 0;
stream.open("ciphertext2");
while ((cypherhexlen < 64) && stream.get(c)) {
    sprintf(arr, "%02x", static_cast<unsigned char>(c));
    cout << arr[0] << arr[1] << " ";
    cipherhex[cypherhexlen] = arr[0];
    cipherhex[cypherhexlen+1] = arr[1];
    cypherhexlen += 2;
}
cipherhex[cypherhexlen] = '\0';
// use cipherhex as needed...
```

Alternatively, I would opt for something more like this instead:

```
ifstream stream;
unsigned char cipher[32];
stream.open("ciphertext2");
stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(cipher), 32);
int cypherlen = stream.gcount();
for(int i = 0; i < cypherlen; ++i) {
    cout << hex << noshowbase << setw(2) << cipher[i] << " ";
}
// use cipher as needed...
```

Comment: This answer enlightened me, now it works great, thank you!