# Read and write .jpg file in C++

Tags: c++

My supervisor developed a simulator (Its a collection of codes) that reads data from a file and converts them to a signal (for example optical signal, etc.), and then the simulator saves this signal to a .sgn file.

He asked me to read a .jpg image in VS 2019 and convert it to a signal of type byte and then save the signal to .sgn file. However, when I save the signal and change its extension to .jpg (in order to make sure that the signal contains the image data) it cannot be open.

I compared the information of the original image and my signal and I see some extra garbage in the signal as shown in pictures.

- **Original image**

[image]

- **Resulted image(Signal image)**

[image]

My questions are (thank you so much in advance):

1. In order to solve this issue, should I read the image header file separately?
2. Am I reading the image file correctly? (the simulator is huge, so I can not put all the codes)
3. Do you have any other idea about where the problem is? like the buffer or something else.

   ```
   std::ifstream inFile;
   inFile.open("1.jpg");

   std::byte out;     // type of output signal

   int length = sizeof(std::byte);
   char * memblock = new char[length];

   for (int i = 0; i < process; i++) {   //this line is related to the circular buffer

   inFile.read(memblock, length);
   std::byte * byte_values = (std::byte*)memblock;
   out = *byte_values;
   outputSignals[0]->bufferPut(out);    // related to saving the output signal
   }
   delete[] memblock;
   ```

Comment: it is probably a compression or header problem, can you post an example of the result image ?

Comment: You just seem to do a straight byte-by-byte copy of the file, without any actual processing of the image. Just like normal copying of the file. And as such, you need to copy the *whole* file (i.e. make sure that `processing` is equal to the byte-size of the input file). If you're supposed to be doing some processing of the actual image inside the JPEG file, then use a library to read and uncompress the image, and process only the image data (not other meta-data in the file, or the compressed image data which is useless).

Comment: ***when I save the signal and change its extension to .jpg (in order to make sure that the signal contains the image data) it cannot be open.*** Just giving data a `.jpg` extension does not make it a valid jpeg file. You need to use a jpeg library to read and write jpeg files.

Comment: `Am I reading the image file correctly?` no you don't read in the file correctly, whenever you read in nontextual data, you have set the input stream to `binary`, otherwise, you might not read everything. The same goes for writing.

Comment: Hi @phoenixstudio,
I have already uploaded the resulted image (signal image) at https://i.stack.imgur.com/kE8bI.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jpeg and similar files contain binary data, hence you should open the file in binary mode for the data to be read correctly.

[Simple Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420317/reading-and-writing-binary-file)