# Converting binary data to readable text using c++

Tags: c++, binary

I have a file with .dat extension which contains some binary data.i want to convert this to readable text format in c++.Read data line by line .

Comment: You will need to know the details of the file format being used. Do you know this? If not this is a reverse engineering task.

Comment: @soniya jain - How do you define _line_ with _some binary data_?

Comment: What is your the line break character in `.data` ? do you know it ?

Comment: Hi all..  Thanks for your prompt response . @Landstalker line break character is \n

Answer (score 0):

You have tried this way?
[Read / Write Binary Data.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420317/reading-and-writing-binary-file)

You can now iterate the data in the buffer and cast them to a char.

Now you can 
[write the chars](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/208416/).

Depending on your encoding the binary data will be "some char".

Linebreaks mostly are '10 or '13'.