# What's correct format and how organize bytes correctly in a .bin file to set in a char array[]?

Tags: c++, arrays, windows, byte

Imagine that following byte array contains all bytes of a executable file (.exe) (that on pratice this not is possible set inside source code because there are much bytes in this file type (.exe) and Visual Studio will crashe)

```
char buffer[] = { 0x60, 0x33, 0xC0, 0x33, 0xDB, 0xEB, 0x00, 0x03, 0xC3 };
```

Then i think that better way to achieve this is [generate all bytes ( PS: like XTEA Runtime Crypter, but without variable declaration ) from .exe file](https://github.com/NateBrune/Simple-XTEA-Crypter/blob/master/xtea.cpp#L77) and insert in a **.bin** file to set on `char buffer[]` later, something like this:

```
vector<char> buffer;

ifstream infile;
infile.open("bytes.bin", ios::binary);
infile.seekg(0, ios::end);
size_t file_size_in_byte = infile.tellg();
buffer.resize(file_size_in_byte);
infile.seekg(0, ios::beg);
infile.read(&buffer[0], file_size_in_byte);
infile.close();
```

Then i ask:

What's correct format of bytes to generate **.bin** file?

1. `0x60, 0x33, 0xC0, 0x33, 0xDB, 0xEB, 0x00, 0x03, 0xC3` - preceded by **0x** and separated by comma and space (like the linked C++ code already makes)?
2. `0x600x330xC00x330xDB0xEB0x000x030xC3` - whitout any space/separation?
3. `60, 33, C0, 33, DB, EB, 00, 03, C3` - separated by comma and space, but not preceded by **0x**?
4. [Like showed in a Hex editor](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/231403/#msg1044561) (not preceded by **0x** and not separated by comma)?

Comment: Formatting values is for humans. Your computer is not a human. It will happily read bytes.

Comment: @IInspectable, then i can [load the executable file directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420317/reading-and-writing-binary-file) to `char buffer[]` (or `vector<char> buffer`) and this will be equivalent to representation > `char buffer[] = { 0x60, 0x33, 0xC0, 0x33, 0xDB, 0xEB, 0x00, 0x03, 0xC3 };` present on *.cpp*?

Comment: Yes. Although that's not an executable. A PE file starts with the bytes `0x4D 0x5A`.

Comment: @IInspectable, thanks for the clarifications. +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't format at all, just write raw bytes. You are reading raw bytes using

```cpp
infile.read(&buffer[0], file_size_in_byte);
```

Similarly, open your output file with `ios::binary` and simply call

```cpp
outfile.write(&buffer[0], some_number_of_bytes);
```

Comment: `infile.read(&buffer[0], file_size_in_byte);` is same that `char buffer[] = { 0x60, 0x33, 0xC0, 0x33, 0xDB, 0xEB, 0x00, 0x03, 0xC3 };` on IDE (source code)?

Comment: I'm supposing that you is considering `infile` == executable file (.exe).

Comment: `infile` is not the executable, it is the file you opened, `bytes.bin`. I'm considering `outfile` to also be `bytes.bin`, or any other file you choose to open for output.

Comment: Then, but how could be the format of content to `bytes.bin`, this not comes in your answer. Read my question one more time please :D.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I understand what you're trying to accomplish, If you are trying to generate C++ source code that contains an array of bytes, then option 1 is probably what you want. What do you mean by "without variable declaration"?