# Not all bytes are showing while reading a file in c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read a file which contain data in binairy mod. The size of the file is 28 bytes but when i try to read this file I only have 22 bytes. I have already tried to modify the info inside the file but it's still missing some bytes. I have no idea why.
PS: I know which data are inside the file but they're not readeable in any kind of computer character encoding standard.
The code used to read the file:

```
std::string line{ "" };
    std::string buffer;
    while (std::getline(file, line))
        buffer += line;
    file.close();
```

Comment: If your data is binary you probably don't want to read it like this especially if your OS is MS Windows.

Comment: You are trying to read binary data as text, which is not going to work.  Google for examples on how to read binary files, or consult a [good c++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/5420568/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5420568/487892)

Comment: I want to read all of binairy data because it's me who put them in. So if i can recover them entierly it's better (obligatory)

Comment: Reading it this way you will not be able to recover the data.

Comment: @IsmaëlGaye: It's definitely possible to read binary files in C++.  `std::string` and `std::getline` are the wrong tools for binary data.  Even `fstream` cannot portably access binary data (it always has a character facet performing text conversions, binary data requires installing a no-op facet, and setting that up is non-portable).

Comment: it works with `std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file), {});` thanks (i have the right number of bytes)

Answer (score 0):

Don't read binary data like its text.
If you want to read binary data into a buffer (e.g., load it into a `std::vector`) here is one recipe that uses stdlib:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

FILE *f = fopen("myfile.bin", "rb");
if (f == nullptr) { /* ... */}
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
auto size = ftell(f);
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
std::vector<uint8_t> buffer(size);
if (fread (buffer.data(), 1, size, f) != size) { /* ... */ }
fclose(f);
```